# Subscription in app purchase from website, Safari web extension and iPhone app

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, safari-extension

We are a monthly subscription service. Currently, we allow users, through our website, to pay for the subscription using either Paypal or a credit card.

We have many different kind of endpoints: Browser extensions (chrome, firefox, edge), add-ins to Word, Outlook, Google Docs, and also an android application.

Now, we want to also have an endpoint for the Safari web extension and an iPhone app.

The question is how to do it.
Since apple requires for the iPhone and Safari extension to allow users to pay also via in-app purchases, the easiest way for us, that would minimize development time and complexity, would be to allow people on the website, to pay also through Apple (in app purchases). Is that possible, or must we create custom code and architecture to allow users to pay directly inside the Safari extension and iphone app?

If we must do it directly, how should this be done? Let's take for example the Safari extension: the user start using the safari extension for free, and at a certain period in time the users wants to upgrade and have a monthly subscription. Where does the user do that? Does he do the payment on our website, or do we have to have some button in the popup.js on the extension that when the user presses it, he gets some popup that allow him to pay, or does he do it directly from within the App Store?

Theoretically, can we allow people to pay with Apple in app purchases via our website, even if we don't have an iphone app and Safari extension?

Answer (score 0):

This question mixes company policy with request for code. For company policy you either inquire Apple or try to build the payment via website and hope they accept it.

If not allowed, you'll need to code regular in-app purchases in the Mac companion app and then have the two communicate.